# Using SetupDI API functions, to disable enable COM port device driver requires running as Administrator

Tags: c++

I need to Disable/Enable a loaded device driver because the device "at times" when connected fails to load properly.
This device is controlled by the user and is POWERED AND UN-POWERED very frequently.
The program which needs to use the driver DETECTS a failure and needs to Disable/Enable which ALWAYS corrects the issue.

But using the SetupAPI methods causes the executable to require ADMIN rights (Windows 7 and Windows 10).
I'm not sure if I need to use "other" coding methods or if SIGNING the executable will remove the "requirement" to run as administrator?

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that is any used can unload a driver, they'd be able to interfere with other users. Drivers are a shared resource.

"Signing" the executable makes a few warnings less scary but doesn't affect security.